# Impossible to make laravel works on Azure Web App Linux

Tags: laravel, azure

I activated a Web App (linux) on Azure. 
Then i imported a Laravel 5.8 fresh installation from local to the app trough FTP.
In local the app works instead on azure i get 500 error when i try to reach the homepage.
Laravel 5.8 has already a web.config file into the public folder so i guess that is not the missing of that file, but should be something else related to the fact that the server is IIS and not Apache.
Any help will be (very) appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to check your error logs to see exactly what the error is. A 500 error can be caused by any number of things. I assume you've installed and set up PHP for IIS?

Comment: laravel error logs does not report anything even is debug is true

Comment: php for iis is installed

Comment: Check your IIS and/or PHP error logs. If it's not a stylized Laravel 500 page, that's probably where the error will show up.

Comment: Are you sure that the Azure WebApp you created be for Linux? Please check it in Azure portal. Actually, Azure WebApp Linux is a Linux container, there is no IIS or Apache in it. To run a PHP app is like use `php -s` command without `web.config` required for IIS.

Comment: If it is for Linux, please see these offical documents https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-php#push-to-azure-from-git and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-php-mysql-app which may helps.

Comment: I just did this actually - it's a bit more of a PITA than you think it's going to be. I jotted down my step by step notes - I'll see if I can compile them in a readable manner and post as an answer

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to assume you've already logged into the Azure SSH Terminal and installed [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) and [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) already.

From [the Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-php) :

**Step 1**:
Login to the Azure CLI

**Step 2**:
Configure a deployment user

```
az webapp deployment user set --user-name <username> --password <password>
```

**Step 3**:
Create a resource group

```
az group create --name myResourceGroup --location "West Europe"
```

**Step 4**:
Create an Azure App Service Plan

```
az appservice plan create --name myAppServicePlan --resource-group myResourceGroup --sku B1 --is-linux
```

**Step 5**:
Create a web app

```
# Bash
az webapp create --resource-group myResourceGroup --plan myAppServicePlan --name <app_name> --runtime "PHP|7.0" --deployment-local-git

# PowerShell
az --% webapp create --resource-group myResourceGroup --plan myAppServicePlan --name <app_name> --runtime "PHP|7.0" --deployment-local-git
```

**Step 6**:
Place the following inside an .htcaccess file inside your Laravel root directory

*This part isn't in the documentation, but it's what solved the issue for me*

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Step 7**:
Head over and check out [projectkudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Custom-Deployment-Script) over at [Github](https://github.com/).

Basically two files, ***.deployment*** and ***deploy.sh*** are added to your Laravel root directory.

Contents of .deployment:

```
[config]
command = bash deploy.sh
```

Contents of deploy.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# ----------------------
# KUDU Deployment Script
# Version: 0.2.2
# ----------------------

# Helpers
# -------

exitWithMessageOnError () {
  if [ ! $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "An error has occurred during web site deployment."
    echo $1
    exit 1
  fi
}

# Prerequisites
# -------------

# Verify node.js installed
hash node 2>/dev/null
exitWithMessageOnError "Missing node.js executable, please install node.js, if already installed make sure it can be reached from current environment."

# Setup
# -----

SCRIPT_DIR="${BASH_SOURCE[0]%\\*}"
SCRIPT_DIR="${SCRIPT_DIR%/*}"
ARTIFACTS=$SCRIPT_DIR/../artifacts
KUDU_SYNC_CMD=${KUDU_SYNC_CMD//\"}

if [[ ! -n "$DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE" ]]; then
  DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE=$SCRIPT_DIR
fi

if [[ ! -n "$NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH" ]]; then
  NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH=$ARTIFACTS/manifest

  if [[ ! -n "$PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH" ]]; then
    PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH=$NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH
  fi
fi

if [[ ! -n "$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET" ]]; then
  DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=$ARTIFACTS/wwwroot
else
  KUDU_SERVICE=true
fi

if [[ ! -n "$KUDU_SYNC_CMD" ]]; then
  # Install kudu sync
  echo Installing Kudu Sync
  npm install kudusync -g --silent
  exitWithMessageOnError "npm failed"

  if [[ ! -n "$KUDU_SERVICE" ]]; then
    # In case we are running locally this is the correct location of kuduSync
    KUDU_SYNC_CMD=kuduSync
  else
    # In case we are running on kudu service this is the correct location of kuduSync
    KUDU_SYNC_CMD=$APPDATA/npm/node_modules/kuduSync/bin/kuduSync
  fi
fi

# Node Helpers
# ------------

selectNodeVersion () {
  if [[ -n "$KUDU_SELECT_NODE_VERSION_CMD" ]]; then
    SELECT_NODE_VERSION="$KUDU_SELECT_NODE_VERSION_CMD \"$DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE\" \"$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET\" \"$DEPLOYMENT_TEMP\""
    eval $SELECT_NODE_VERSION
    exitWithMessageOnError "select node version failed"

    if [[ -e "$DEPLOYMENT_TEMP/__nodeVersion.tmp" ]]; then
      NODE_EXE=`cat "$DEPLOYMENT_TEMP/__nodeVersion.tmp"`
      exitWithMessageOnError "getting node version failed"
    fi

    if [[ -e "$DEPLOYMENT_TEMP/.tmp" ]]; then
      NPM_JS_PATH=`cat "$DEPLOYMENT_TEMP/__npmVersion.tmp"`
      exitWithMessageOnError "getting npm version failed"
    fi

    if [[ ! -n "$NODE_EXE" ]]; then
      NODE_EXE=node
    fi

    NPM_CMD="\"$NODE_EXE\" \"$NPM_JS_PATH\""
  else
    NPM_CMD=npm
    NODE_EXE=node
  fi
}

##################################################################################################################################
# Deployment
# ----------

echo Handling node.js deployment.

# 1. KuduSync
if [[ "$IN_PLACE_DEPLOYMENT" -ne "1" ]]; then
  "$KUDU_SYNC_CMD" -v 50 -f "$DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE" -t "$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET" -n "$NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH" -p "$PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH" -i ".git;.hg;.deployment;deploy.sh"
  exitWithMessageOnError "Kudu Sync failed"
fi

# 2. Select node version
selectNodeVersion

# 3. Install NPM packages
if [ -e "$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET/package.json" ]; then
  cd "$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET"
  eval $NPM_CMD install --production
  exitWithMessageOnError "npm failed"
  cd - > /dev/null
fi

# 4. Install Bower modules
if [ -e "$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET/bower.json" ]; then
  cd "$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET"
  eval ./node_modules/.bin/bower install
  exitWithMessageOnError "bower failed"
  cd - > /dev/null
fi

# 5. Install Composer modules 
if [ -e "$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET/composer.json" ]; then
  cd "$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET"
  eval php composer.phar install
  exitWithMessageOnError "composer failed"
  cd - > /dev/null
fi

##################################################################################################################################

# Post deployment stub
if [[ -n "$POST_DEPLOYMENT_ACTION" ]]; then
  POST_DEPLOYMENT_ACTION=${POST_DEPLOYMENT_ACTION//\"}
  cd "${POST_DEPLOYMENT_ACTION_DIR%\\*}"
  "$POST_DEPLOYMENT_ACTION"
  exitWithMessageOnError "post deployment action failed"
fi

echo "Finished successfully."
```

**Step 8**:
Assuming you're using [Git](https://git-scm.com/), (if you're not - why not??), push to Azure

```
git remote add azure <deploymentLocalGitUrl-from-create-step>
git push azure master
```

You didn't mention interacting with a DB specifically, but you should [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-php-mysql-app) is a good read for that.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, this will help someone using Azure tutorial app : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-php-mysql-app?pivots=platform-linux
I got the same error 500. Problem is that when you push the code, the deploy.sh runs and it errors on line 111 where error happens because php is not installed.
I commented out the line in .deploy file to run the bash deploy.sh and pushed code again and then it ran fine, by installing  php, then the dependencies for laravel etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to make it work (sorry if its too late, started with Laravel this year).

After uploading all files make sure to use Kudu console to access the CMD terminal and copy the .env.example to the root of your app. Once done it is important to set up .env correctly and run:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

This will write the key on your env file.

After that it should run.

Do not forget to map the routes to your public folder.